# Convert Array Objects key value pairs properties to a single key value pair and insert it into array again

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a js array

```
var array = [ {no: 50, name: 'Ajinkya'}, {no: 89, name: 'Akshay'}, {no: 29, name: 'Rajesh'}, {no: 15, name: 'Vikram'}, ]
```

want to convert it into an array

```
var array = [50:'Ajinkya', 89:'Akshay', 29:Rajesh, 15: 'Vikram']
```

I have tried this

```
array.forEach(
 function(x){
 temp[x['no']] = x['name'];
})
```

But its not giving expected result

Comment: *something* is not valid javascript. do you mean a single object?

Comment: The code you tried would work if you correctly initialized `temp` to `{ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that `50:'Ajinkya'` is array which 50th element is 'Ajinkya' then

```
[{ no: 50, name: 'Ajinkya' },
{ no: 89, name: 'Akshay' },
{ no: 29, name: 'Rajesh' },
{ no: 15, name: 'Vikram' }].reduce((acc, prev) => {
  acc[prev.no] = prev.name;
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: @newbee, if I got your task right - it is ok. Because 89th element gives array with 90 len. Otherwise, if you wanted an object with fields as {50: 'Ajinkya'} it is different (you should update your question and substitute `[]` with `{}` if so)

Comment: sorry sychd, i was a bit confused. I got the solution now. Thanks for the kind response.

Answer (score 1):

You could map objects with the wanted key/value pairs and assign them to a single object.

Methods used:

- [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for creating a single object out of some objects,
- [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for taking an array as parameters,
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for transforming the objects,
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for separating the properties,
- [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for creating new objects.

```js
var array = [{ no: 50, name: 'Ajinkya' }, { no: 89, name: 'Akshay' }, { no: 29, name: 'Rajesh' }, { no: 15, name: 'Vikram' }],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(({ no, name }) => ({ [no]: name })));
    
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const array1 = [ {no: 50, name: 'Ajinkya'}, {no: 89, name: 'Akshay'}, {no: 29, name: 'Rajesh'}, {no: 15, name: 'Vikram'} ];

const array2 = {} ;

for (const itm of array1) {
      array2[itm.no] =itm.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would reduce the array into a object where you can look up the items by id. An array doesn't really make sense here.

```js
    const array = [ {no: 50, name: 'Ajinkya'}, {no: 89, name: 'Akshay'}, {no: 29, name: 'Rajesh'}, {no: 15, name: 'Vikram'}, ];
    
    const newStructure = array.reduce((acc, {no,name}) => {
        acc[no] = name;
        return acc;
    }, {});

    console.log(newStructure);
```